# Taking info from file and creating a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

The goal of mine is to create a dictionary called 'sum_of_department' contains the department as the key and the total annual salary of all employees combined as a value. So far this is what I have but I'm a bit lost on how to add all the department names along with a sum of all of the employees salary in that dictionary. The current dictionary i tried displays only the amount of the salary and how many times its seen in the file. this is where i need the help.

```
 import requests


# endpoint
endpoint = "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xzkq-xp2w.json"

# optional parameters
parameters = {"$limit":20,}

# make request
response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)

# Get the response data as a python object. 
data = response.json()

count_by_department = {}
sum_by_department = {}

#loop through the data
for i in data:
  if ('department' and 'salary_or_hourly' and 'annual_salary' in i):
    department = i['department']
    pay_type = i['salary_or_hourly']
    anual_salary = i['annual_salary']
    # print(i['annual_salary'])
  else:
  # handle case where there is no department property in that record
    department = 'undefined'
    pay_type = 'n/a'
    anual_salary = 'n/a'
  # print(department,"," ,pay_type)

  # exclude the cases where the pay type is Hourly
  if(pay_type != 'Salary' ):
    pay_type = 0
  # print(department,"," ,pay_type)





  # update the sum_by_department and count_by_department dictionaries
  if (department in count_by_department):
        count_by_department[department] += 1

  else:
        count_by_department[department] = 1

  if (anual_salary in sum_by_department):
    sum_by_department[anual_salary] +=1
  else:
    sum_by_department[anual_salary] = 1

# print(count_by_department)
# print(sum_by_department)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add each person's `annual_salary` to the `sum_by_department` array while looping. Also, do not forget to convert your `annual_salary` variable to the `float` type, because adding them together as strings won't work.

Example script:

```
import requests


# endpoint
endpoint = "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/xzkq-xp2w.json"

# optional parameters
parameters = {"$limit":20,}

# make request
response = requests.get(endpoint, params=parameters)

# Get the response data as a python object. 
data = response.json()

count_by_department = {}
sum_by_department = {}

#loop through the data
for i in data:
  if ('department' and 'salary_or_hourly' and 'annual_salary' in i):
    department = i['department']
    pay_type = i['salary_or_hourly']
    annual_salary = float(i['annual_salary'])
    # print(i['annual_salary'])
  else:
  # handle case where there is no department property in that record
    department = 'undefined'
    pay_type = 'n/a'
    annual_salary = 0
  # print(department,"," ,pay_type)

  # exclude the cases where the pay type is Hourly
  if(pay_type != 'Salary' ):
    pay_type = 0
  # print(department,"," ,pay_type)

  # update the sum_by_department and count_by_department dictionaries
  if (department in count_by_department):
        count_by_department[department] += 1
        sum_by_department[department] += annual_salary

  else:
        count_by_department[department] = 1
        sum_by_department[department] = annual_salary


  #import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
print('count_by_department = ', count_by_department)
print('sum_by_department = ', sum_by_department)
```

**Tip**:
Uncomment the pdb line to debug interactively. The Python Debugger (pdb for short) halts the program while it's still running (i.e. in memory), so you can interact with it and inspect all variables.

Comment: Thank you. I still have a question.  You day to grab each persons salary and add them.  Which ues its part of the goal. But how would I add that salary to the total department salary.  Based on where that person works?

Comment: Disregard i just ran the code and i get what is happening. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help. An upvote / accepting the answer would be helpful for me!